# What is the reason for considering a Banach space in the following theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

**Theorem** $:$

Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ be a Banach space. Let $T:X \longrightarrow X$ be a continuous linear transformation. Suppose $a=\|T\| < 1$. Then there exists $S:X \longrightarrow X$ such that $ST=TS=I$.

**Proof** $:$

Define for each $n \ge 0,$ $S_n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} T^k = I + T +T^2 + \cdots + T^n$. Then $S_n$ is bounded and linear.

$$S_n (I-T) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} T^k (I-T)
= {\sum_{k=0}^{n} T^k} - {T \sum_{k=0}^{n} T^k}
= {\sum_{k=0}^{n} T^k} - {\sum_{k=0}^{n} T^{k+1}} 
= I - T^{n+1}$$

$\implies S_n (I - T) (x) = (I- T^{n+1}) (x)$.

$\implies x-S_n(I-T) (x) = T^{n+1} (x)$.

So,

$$\|x - S_n(I-T) (x) \| = \|T^{n+1} (x) \| \le \|T^{n+1}\| \|x\| \le \|T\|^{n+1} \|x\| = a^{n+1} \|x\| \rightarrow 0$$

$\implies S_n(I-T) (x) \rightarrow x$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ for all $x \in X$. i.e. $S_n(I-T) \rightarrow I$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. So, $(I-T) \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} T^n = I$.

$\implies \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} T^n = (I-T)^{-1}$.

This completes the proof.

I don't understand the proof. What does the result obtained in this proof signify? How do I find $S$ from here. Is $S = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} T^n$? If 'yes' then $ST=TS$ holds but it equals to $S-I$, not equals to $I$. Also I don't understand where the Banach space condition is used in the proof. Please help me in this regard.

Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: Have you seen that a linear map between normed spaces is continuous if and only if it is bounded? You should use that to show that $S_n$ as defined in the first sentence is bounded.

Comment: $ST=TS=I$ is not correct! What is correct is $S(T-I)=(T-I)=I$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $S=\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty T^n$. You need the fact that the space is complete in order to prove that this series converges. And, yes, $ST=TS\ne\operatorname{Id}$. My guess is that the statement of the theorem is that$$(\operatorname{Id}-T)S=S(\operatorname{Id}-T)=\operatorname{Id}$$because that's what was proved.

Comment: Would you please edit my post @José Carlos Santos?

Comment: @Dbchatto67 Done.

Comment: What is the use of Banach space? Can you please elaborate this fact?

Comment: Why does $(\operatorname{Id}-T)T=T(\operatorname{Id}-T)=\operatorname{Id}?$

Comment: @Dbchatto67 It was a typo. I meant to write that $$(\operatorname{Id}-T)S=S(\operatorname{Id}-T)=\operatorname{Id}.$$

Comment: Then is the theorem wrong?

Comment: Our instructor has given us the proof.

Comment: Concerning the fact that we're dealing with a Banach space: for each $x\in X$, the sequsence $\bigl(S_n(x)\bigr)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Cauche sequence. Since the space is a Banach space, it converges. That's how we know that the definition of $S$ makes sense.

Comment: I suppose that your instructor meant that$$(\operatorname{Id}-T)S=S(\operatorname{Id}-T)=\operatorname{Id}.$$

Comment: Yes. The limit of a sequence of linear operators, when it exists, is always a linear operator.

Comment: But he has written on the black board just what exactly I have written here @José Carlos Santos.

Comment: If you want I can add a image of it what I have copied.

Comment: My guess is that your instructor is a human being, like you and me. And human beings make mistakes.

Comment: I have added the image of my copy @José Carlos Santos.